# Rewrite Module from 200 OK to 201 Created

Tags: xml, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, response

I am trying with the above XML the following :

When it matches 200 should return 202 (it works), but it returns 202 to all of the requests, even when it should return 400.
I am trying to find how this will work but I keep getting 202 even if it should return 400 or something else. How can I do it only in IIS and not change something in my API .net app?

```
<rule name="SetStatusTo202ForSuccess" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="item-base-data" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
  <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="200" />
 </conditions>
<action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="202" subStatusCode="200" statusReason="Accepted" statusDescription="." />
<serverVariables>
  <set name="RESPONSE_STATUS" value="202" />
</serverVariables>
</rule>
```

I tried, inbound rule and outbound rules. In outbound rules I tried the below:

```
<rule name="ChangeStatusCode" preCondition="Is200StatusCode" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
<match serverVariable="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="200" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="202" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
<preCondition name="Is200StatusCode">
<add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="200" />
</preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Comment: Your rule will return 202 to all requests, which means that all requests match this rule, so what you need to change is the matching parameter in the rule so that it only matches 200. When the request returns 400, the matching condition should not match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any specific parameter for the rewrite I want to do? I've tried many different solutions, but none works as expected. It seems that the conditions are not being met correctly. 
Also, to what you refer as a matching parameter? Logical group field?
Thank you.

Comment: You can give an example of the requested url when it should return 400, I will make demo for you.